# Installing MDS Excel Add-In Issue with Prerequisites

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012, master-data-services

I am attempting to install the [Master Data Services Plugin for Excel](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35581), but can't get the install to actually process due to it saying the prerequisites are not installed:

[image: Prerequisites Message]

I have made sure I have the right version (32 bit) to match my version of excel (2010), and have the full version of .net 4.5 installed.  If I try to install the full version of .net 4.0, I am told that the newer (4.5) version already is installed.

Here are some links with similar issues, but no response:
[Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/2012-master-data-services-excel-add-in/defbdec0-f37c-4911-8804-f6aef9fcb648); [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/742256/master-data-services-2012-excel-add-in-installation-error);

Has anyone else faced this issue and got around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this looks to be a simple fix. The installer needs to be run as administrator, but in order to do that you have to run it through the command prompt as administrator. After doing this, it installed ok.

I'm not sure why the installer didn't request elevated privileges, but I'm guessing it couldn't properly query the system to verify the necessary prerequisites were installed.

Hopefully this helps someone else in the future!